# MySql UPDATE error. c#

Tags: c#, mysql

ionline - class, string myname

```
private static void SetOnlineStatus(PacketHeader header, Connection connection, ionline message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Check online: " + message.myname);
        MySqlCommand mycmd = new MySqlCommand();
        mycmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?user";
        mycmd.Connection = mconnection;
        mycmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("user", message.myname);
        MySqlDataReader Reader = mycmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (Reader.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Check online: " + message.myname+" "+GetDBString("username",Reader));
            MySqlCommand mycmd2 = new MySqlCommand();
            mycmd2.CommandText = "UPDATE users SET online = 0 WHERE userid = @user2";
            mycmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user2", Reader.GetInt32("userid"));
            mycmd2.Connection = mconnection;
            Console.WriteLine(mycmd2.ExecuteNonQuery().ToString());
        }


    }
```

Mysql request "mycmd2" isn't executed . What in my query not the correct?

Comment: mconnection is probably the thing that's disposed which has nothing to do with your query.

Comment: Can you post all your code, including the part where mconnection is declared?

Comment: Can you provide more information? i.e. Code, line that generates the exception...

Comment: What for ? other sql queries are executed!

Comment: please be clear on question. The error you pasted is not clear. Add more information otherwise your question will be downvoted and closed

Comment: UPDATE  `shachat`.`users` SET  `online` =  '0' WHERE  `users`.`userid` =3;  - phpmyadmin , how to convert phpmyadmin to c# code ? :)

Comment: Added code to the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While a DataReader is open its connection is busy serving the reader.
The connection cannot be used to make other operations on the database.
You should get an exception though.

If your first query returns zero or one row, then you could simplify your code using the ExecuteScalar method and removing the need to use a MySqlDataReader

```
    Console.WriteLine("Check online: " + message.myname);
    MySqlCommand mycmd = new MySqlCommand();
    mycmd.CommandText = "SELECT userid FROM users WHERE username = ?user";
    mycmd.Connection = mconnection;
    mycmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("user", message.myname);
    object result = mycmd.ExecuteScalar();
    if(result != null)
    {
        int userID = Convert.ToInt32(result);
        MySqlCommand mycmd2 = new MySqlCommand();
        mycmd2.CommandText = "UPDATE users SET online = 0 WHERE userid = @user2";
        mycmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user2", userID);
        mycmd2.Connection = mconnection;
        mycmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```